# Can't debug an application on Win CE 6.0 with VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I'm trying to get debugging working for a Windows CE 6.0 application but I cannot even start the debugging process. I can run a "Hello World" application OK but when I try to run my app which is linked against another DLL I don't get any error but debuggin does not start. The DLL is present in the same folder as the executable.

This are the logs from VS2005.

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: protobuf_lite, Configuration: Release SDK3 (ARMV4I) ------
>   2>------ Deploy started: Project: libus_cqlink_msg, Configuration: Release SDK3 (ARMV4I) ------
>   3>------ Deploy started: Project: libus_cqlink_nw, Configuration: Release SDK3 (ARMV4I) ------
>   4>------ Deploy started: Project: libus_cqlink_cli, Configuration: Release SDK3 (ARMV4I) ------
>   5>------ Deploy started: Project: CtrlClientWinCE, Configuration: Release SDK3 (ARMV4I) ------
>   ========== Deploy: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I also checked dependencies on Executable on Win CE device using peinfo.exe.

This is the log from peinfo.e

> Necessary library file(s):
>     libus_cqlink_cli.dll Is loadable
>     COREDLL.dll Is loadable
>     commctrl.dll Is loadable
>     ole32.dll Is loadable
>     OLEAUT32.dll Is loadable
>
> Imports Table:
>     libus_cqlink_cli.dll
>     OrigFirstThunk:  0016D3AC (Unbound IAT)
>     ForwarderChain:  00000000
>     First thunk RVA: 0016E710
>
> Ordn  Name
>      11  ?instance@USPlatformMgr@cs@@SAPAV12@XZ (Bound to: 0016D3E4)
>
> COREDLL.dll

I can not figure out what's wrong I am doing.

Please suggest.

Comment: @ctacke: Do you have any idea what is going wrong? There was one dll missing MSVCR80.dll, that I copied on my Win CE device. But still it does not get launched.

Comment: If I knew, I would have answered.  If you just run the deployed application by double-clicking it, what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens if I double click on executable. Is there any other way to check missing dependency?

Comment: if it were a missing dependency, double-clicking it would show a dialog telling you there is a missing dependency.  I'd try a simple console app and work up from that.

Comment: @RonakPatel try increasing memory level for Storage Memory, its in control panel -> System Properties -> Memory on your device. Its possible that there is no room for debugger files.

Comment: I think above would make sense if you even was not able to use 'Attach to Process' to list processes on your device.

Comment: @marcin_j : Sure I will give a try with settings you suggested on Monday. And will respond you how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: @marcin_j : Perfect. It worked. Big Thanks. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows CE devices are very often configured with minimal free space for Storage Memory. While using debugger VS must copy some files to Storage Memory (ie. \Windows folder), and if there is not enough space it fails. The solution is to increasing memory level for Storage Memory, its in control panel -> System Properties -> Memory on your device.