# VS2008 and Device connection

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am attempting to debug code on a device running ce 5.0 and CF 3.5.   Connection can be made via VS2008.  Programs are deployed however just prior to run VS2008 hangs.   Never gets to program execution.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the program run off the debugger okay? If it does, verify you have the latest USB drivers for your motherboard or USB chipset. Does it work from a different computer? Does Ethernet debug work?

Comment: maybe thats similar problem to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533138/cant-debug-an-application-on-win-ce-6-0-with-vs2005/23626278#23626278